# Is it possible to do a multiple exposure on an Olympus 35sp?

Tags: film, olympus, rangefinder

I am a big fan of double exposures in film photography, and was hoping to try my hand at it.

I have an [Olympus 35sp](http://www.cameraquest.com/olysp.htm) and it is an amazing 35mm rangefinder.

Like most film cameras, it has a rewind button that allows you to rewind the film. If you hold it down while you "advance" the film and reset the shutter, the film does not advance and you can shoot again on the same frame. But here is where the trouble starts.

The rewind button doesn't "unpop" immediately, and when you advance the film again, it unpops mid-stroke, and the film only advances part of the way. So the frame that you've already shot twice will only move about halfway, so you're left taking another half-frame on it. You can't advance the film again until you activate the shutter, so it appears the whole endeavor is intractable.

Has anyone done this or faced down the same issue with other Olympus rangefinders (i.e. the RC or RD?)

Comment: A quick google shows perhaps something similiar? [here](https://www.flickr.com/groups/76025786@N00/discuss/72157612199103758/)

Comment: @rfusca Thanks for pointing me there. I had checked that out and unfortunately on that thread they tackle the first part (cocking the shutter w/out advancing the film) but not the second (advancing the frame _all the way_ when you cock the shutter for the next (non-double exposed) shot. Sad face.

Comment: Sorry, wish I could help more, but I've never done film work.

Comment: The next exposure _after_ the completed double-exposure needs to be done with lens cap on, as I wrote in my answer to the other similar/duplicate question. There is no other workaround to it that I'm aware of.

Comment: @EsaPaulasto thanks! I didn't see that question until now. That makes a ton of sense. I can waste a half-frame if I need to.